# how to get a batch file running using java

Tags: java

i have a batch file saved on my desktop and it serves the purpose of opening a calculator when executed.
i want this batch file to function quite in the same way using java. i wrote the following command in netbeans

```
package runbatch;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Runbatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c hello.bat");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Runbatch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

although i get the build to be successful i am not getting the calculator opened up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start calculator.bat");
```

Or you can execute your program without going through a batch file, like so:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start java NameOfJavaFile");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "start" argument and complete path of batch file:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start D:\sandbox\src\runbatch\hello.bat");
This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer something like this:

```
String pathToExecutable = "C:/Program Files/calculator.exe";

try
{
    final List<String> processBuilderCommand = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Here you can add other commands too eg a bat or other exe
    processBuilderCommand.add(pathToExecutable);

    final ProcessBuilder processbuilder = new ProcessBuilder(processBuilderCommand);
    // Here you be able to add some additional infos to the process, some variables
    final Map<String, String> environment = processbuilder.environment();
    environment.put("AUTOBATCHNOPROGRESS", "no");

    processbuilder.inheritIO();
    final Process start = processbuilder.start();

    start.waitFor();
}
catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)
{
    LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
}
```

i think it's a little bit flexibel then the others because you can add several and more then one execuable und you be able to add variables.

Answer (score 0):

ProcessBuilder is the safe and right way of doing this in java :

```
String[] command = new String[]{"cmd", "/c" ,"hello.bat"};
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command(command);
processBuilder.start();
```